# G++/GCC: how to make your app tell OS to download libs it needs into system?

Tags: c++, c, linux, dependencies

So for example I am creating some app that uses boost or openCV and on my developer machine all that is installed so app compiles without any problem. But I wonder how to make app tell OS to download libs I use on first run? Is it possible? (sorry - I am linux noob)

Comment: with a launcher it's possible, if the lib is not installed, the application don't start at all

Comment: I have added a 'linux' tag. You should probably retag it with the specific version of your linux distribution... Once this gets into the gory details on how to install a lib it will become dependent on the actual distribution (debian/redhat...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what package managers are for. What you do is you compile your project, and then you build a package (e.g. .deb or .rpm), using the appropriate tools. While doing so, you can specify where the various files in your package should go, but also which other packages your package relies on. These are known as "dependencies", and package managers like apt and rpm are pretty good at resolving them.

Here's the official debian guide to making packages to give you an idea:
http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/

Alternatively, you can just distribute your program as-is and list the dependencies in the install instructions; users will then have to manually install them through their package manager before running your program.